# Multi-boot 3 OS Grub recovery/configuration

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, boot, grub

so right now I have 3 OS installations on my laptop: 2 Windows 10 and 1 Ubuntu.

I first installed my 1º Windows, then Ubuntu and now I installed my 2º Windows 10.

The thing is before I installed the last one, GRUB was fine (the entry menu was working perfect). After the 2º Windows installation there was no change so I ran "boot-repair" on Ubuntu and now the laptop automatically launchs the "Windows boot window" (don't know the exact name).

My question is: how can I recover GRUB and then make the 2 Windows entries work (on GRUB, not on the "windows boot manager")?

Thank you.

(By the way, if you are wondering why I want 2 Windows 10 installations is because I want to separate my private and working installation).

Comment: What style is hard disk - GPT or MBR? One HD or more HD?

Comment: (I should had added that, sorry) So it's one HD and it's GPT "style". Thank you.

Comment: Consider just visualizing your environments to simplify at some point.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not afraid of using command line I would suggest using it, also the steps for graphical "Boot-Repair" are given:

[How to reinstall GRUB using Ubuntu live CD/USB - official docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)

When booting Ubuntu USB or CD/DVD select UEFI boot, like "USB UEFI" for example.